# Use SCSS in AppScript while making an add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, sass, google-workspace-add-ons

Is there a way by which I can use SCSS in appscript while making an add-on.

Currently I am able to use css by including the style tag in the html file.

Comment: Have you checked on using it from a [CDN link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/sass.js/0.9.2)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to include SCSS in html? If yes, you can't do that.

You need transpile SASS/SCSS to CSS. Then, include css into your html.

There are lots of ways to transpile but simplest way is the following.

```
$ npm install -g sass
$ sass main.sass to main.scss
```